# jquery validator addClassRules method not applying to all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am new to jquery validator. I have been stuck here and need some help

I have some `input` fields with different `class` for each of them. I want to validate them using jquery validator by adding rules by `addClassRules` method.

The problem is that adding of class rules works on the first rule but then afterwards it doesn't work.

Below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Simple DataTable</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<div class="container" >
<h1>Welcome to boostrap</h1>
</div>

<form>
    <table>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="abc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="jkl"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="xyz"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="abc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="jkl"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="xyz"/></td>
        </tr>


    </table>


    <input type="submit" />
</form>

</center>
</body>
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.validator.addClassRules({
        abc:{
            required:true
        },
        jkl:{
            required:true
        },
        xyz:{
            required:true
        }

    });



    $("form").validate();
});

</script>
</html>
```

The documentation at:

https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/

mentions the same thing what I have done. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `name` attributes on the `input` elements to make it work. You can see this in the snippet below. I've set the `debug` property on the  `validate` to true to highlight this. It will say e.g.:

> `<input type="text" class="abc error" aria-required="true">` has no name assigned

Also you need to call the `valid` method as well to get the errors to show up on the form.

So in the snippet you can try:

- Submit with errors - will show the `input`s in the first row are flagged as having no `name` attribute
- Submit with no errors (first run the snippet again) - adds some `name` attributes to the first row and you get the desired output.

Note the snippet function doesn't allow a form submit so I wrapped the validate and valid methods in button clicks to simulate the form submit. See [this link on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339479/advise-that-submit-events-on-forms-does-not-work-on-code-snippets).

HTH

```js
$("#test1").on("click", function() {
  // add rules
  $.validator.addClassRules({
    abc: {
      required: true
    },
    jkl: {
      required: true
    },
    xyz: {
      required: true
    }
  });
  // validate form
  $("form").validate({debug: true});
  $("form").valid();
});

$("#test2").on("click", function() {
  // add name attributes to first row
  $("td:eq(0)").children(0).attr("name", "foo1");
  $("td:eq(1)").children(0).attr("name", "foo2");
  $("td:eq(2)").children(0).attr("name", "foo3");
  // add rules
  $.validator.addClassRules({
    abc: {
      required: true
    },
    jkl: {
      required: true
    },
    xyz: {
      required: true
    }
  });
  // validate form
  $("form").validate({debug: true});
  $("form").valid();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<center>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Welcome to boostrap</h1>
  </div>

  <form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="abc" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="jkl" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="xyz" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input name="foo4" type="text" class="abc" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="foo5" type="text" class="jkl" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="foo6" type="text" class="xyz" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339479/advise-that-submit-events-on-forms-does-not-work-on-code-snippets
    <input type="submit" />-->
    <input type="button" name="test1" id="test1" value="Submit with errors" />
    <input type="button" name="test2" id="test2" value="Submit with no errors" />
  </form>

</center>
```

Comment: Excellent. that worked, is this mentioned in documentation of jquery validator ?

Comment: Fourth paragraph under `Markup Recommendations`: https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/.